# Failed to connect to my own azure cosmos db instance using ScalarDB

Tags: java, azure, azure-cosmosdb, scalardb

While i was testing the functionality of cosmosdb of the scalardb (2.2.0), i couldn’t connect to the azure cosmos db instance via scalardb, when i try to initialize the DistributedTransaction or the Cosmos object with the following code

```
DatabaseConfig cosmosDBConfig = new DatabaseConfig(f);
            Cosmos cosmos = new Cosmos(cosmosDBConfig);
DistributedTransactionManager db = Guice.createInjector(new TransactionModule(cosmosDBConfig))
        .getInstance(TransactionService.class); // failed here
// also tried with this
// Cosmos cosmos = new Cosmos(cosmosDBConfig); // fail here
```

and I got the following errors

```
Network failure
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: port out of range:-1
        at java.net.InetSocketAddress.checkPort(InetSocketAddress.java:143)
        at java.net.InetSocketAddress.<init>(InetSocketAddress.java:188)
        at reactor.netty.tcp.InetSocketAddressUtil.createForIpString(InetSocketAddressUtil.java:88)
        at reactor.netty.tcp.InetSocketAddressUtil.createInetSocketAddress(InetSocketAddressUtil.java:74)
        at reactor.netty.tcp.InetSocketAddressUtil.createUnresolved(InetSocketAddressUtil.java:48)
        at reactor.netty.tcp.TcpUtils._updatePort(TcpUtils.java:91)
        at reactor.netty.tcp.TcpUtils.updatePort(TcpUtils.java:73)
        at reactor.netty.tcp.TcpClient.lambda$port$5(TcpClient.java:411)
        at reactor.netty.tcp.TcpClientBootstrap.configure(TcpClientBootstrap.java:39)
        at reactor.netty.tcp.TcpClientBootstrap.configure(TcpClientBootstrap.java:39)
        at reactor.netty.tcp.TcpClientBootstrap.configure(TcpClientBootstrap.java:39)
        at reactor.netty.tcp.TcpClientBootstrap.configure(TcpClientBootstrap.java:39)
        at reactor.netty.tcp.TcpClient.connect(TcpClient.java:196)
        at reactor.netty.http.client.HttpClientFinalizer.connect(HttpClientFinalizer.java:68)
        at reactor.netty.http.client.HttpClientFinalizer.responseConnection(HttpClientFinalizer.java:85)
        at com.azure.cosmos.implementation.http.ReactorNettyClient.send(ReactorNettyClient.java:123)
        at com.azure.cosmos.implementation.RxGatewayStoreModel.performRequest(RxGatewayStoreModel.java:159)
        at com.azure.cosmos.implementation.RxGatewayStoreModel.read(RxGatewayStoreModel.java:91)
        at com.azure.cosmos.implementation.RxGatewayStoreModel.invokeAsyncInternal(RxGatewayStoreModel.java:351)
        at com.azure.cosmos.implementation.RxGatewayStoreModel.lambda$invokeAsync$3(RxGatewayStoreModel.java:366)
        at com.azure.cosmos.implementation.BackoffRetryUtility.lambda$executeRetry$0(BackoffRetryUtility.java:34)
        at reactor.core.publisher.MonoDefer.subscribe(MonoDefer.java:44)
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxRetryWhen.subscribe(FluxRetryWhen.java:79)
        at reactor.core.publisher.MonoRetryWhen.subscribeOrReturn(MonoRetryWhen.java:46)
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxFromMonoOperator.subscribe(FluxFromMonoOperator.java:76)
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxDefer.subscribe(FluxDefer.java:54)
        at reactor.core.publisher.InternalMonoOperator.subscribe(InternalMonoOperator.java:64)
        at reactor.core.publisher.MonoFlatMap$FlatMapMain.onNext(MonoFlatMap.java:150)
        at reactor.core.publisher.MonoDelay$MonoDelayRunnable.run(MonoDelay.java:117)
        at reactor.core.scheduler.SchedulerTask.call(SchedulerTask.java:68)
        at reactor.core.scheduler.SchedulerTask.call(SchedulerTask.java:28)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$201(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180)
        at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:293)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Failed to retrieve database account information. java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: port out of range:-1
Fail to reach global gateway [scalardb-test-cosmos.cassandra.cosmos.azure.com], [null]
startRefreshLocationTimerAsync() - Unable to refresh database account from any location. Exception: CosmosException{userAgent=Linux/4.18.0-147.8.1.el8_1.x86_64 JRE/1.8.0_252 cosmosdb-java-sdk/4.1.0, error=null, resourceAddress='null', requestUri='null', statusCode=0, message=null, causeInfo=[class: class java.lang.IllegalArgumentException, message: port out of range:-1], responseHeaders={}, requestHeaders=[Accept=application/json, x-ms-date=Thu, 01 Oct 2020 09:28:49 GMT]}
CosmosException{userAgent=Linux/4.18.0-147.8.1.el8_1.x86_64 JRE/1.8.0_252 cosmosdb-java-sdk/4.1.0, error=null, resourceAddress='null', requestUri='null', statusCode=0, message=null, causeInfo=[class: class java.lang.IllegalArgumentException, message: port out of range:-1], responseHeaders={}, requestHeaders=[Accept=application/json, x-ms-date=Thu, 01 Oct 2020 09:28:49 GMT]}
        at com.azure.cosmos.BridgeInternal.createCosmosException(BridgeInternal.java:281)
        at com.azure.cosmos.implementation.RxGatewayStoreModel.lambda$toDocumentServiceResponse$2(RxGatewayStoreModel.java:301)
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxOnErrorResume$ResumeSubscriber.onError(FluxOnErrorResume.java:88)
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxMapFuseable$MapFuseableSubscriber.onError(FluxMapFuseable.java:134)
        at reactor.core.publisher.MonoFlatMap$FlatMapMain.onError(MonoFlatMap.java:165)
        at reactor.core.publisher.MonoSingle$SingleSubscriber.onError(MonoSingle.java:141)
        at reactor.core.publisher.Operators.error(Operators.java:196)
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxFlatMap.trySubscribeScalarMap(FluxFlatMap.java:134)
        at reactor.core.publisher.MonoFlatMapMany.subscribeOrReturn(MonoFlatMapMany.java:49)
        at reactor.core.publisher.InternalMonoOperator.subscribe(InternalMonoOperator.java:57)
        at reactor.core.publisher.MonoDefer.subscribe(MonoDefer.java:52)
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxRetryWhen.subscribe(FluxRetryWhen.java:79)
        at reactor.core.publisher.MonoRetryWhen.subscribeOrReturn(MonoRetryWhen.java:46)
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxFromMonoOperator.subscribe(FluxFromMonoOperator.java:76)
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxDefer.subscribe(FluxDefer.java:54)
        at reactor.core.publisher.InternalMonoOperator.subscribe(InternalMonoOperator.java:64)
        at reactor.core.publisher.MonoFlatMap$FlatMapMain.onNext(MonoFlatMap.java:150)
        at reactor.core.publisher.MonoDelay$MonoDelayRunnable.run(MonoDelay.java:117)
        at reactor.core.scheduler.SchedulerTask.call(SchedulerTask.java:68)
        at reactor.core.scheduler.SchedulerTask.call(SchedulerTask.java:28)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$201(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180)
        at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:293)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: port out of range:-1
        at java.net.InetSocketAddress.checkPort(InetSocketAddress.java:143)
        at java.net.InetSocketAddress.<init>(InetSocketAddress.java:188)
        at reactor.netty.tcp.InetSocketAddressUtil.createForIpString(InetSocketAddressUtil.java:88)
        at reactor.netty.tcp.InetSocketAddressUtil.createInetSocketAddress(InetSocketAddressUtil.java:74)
        at reactor.netty.tcp.InetSocketAddressUtil.createUnresolved(InetSocketAddressUtil.java:48)
        at reactor.netty.tcp.TcpUtils._updatePort(TcpUtils.java:91)
        at reactor.netty.tcp.TcpUtils.updatePort(TcpUtils.java:73)
        at reactor.netty.tcp.TcpClient.lambda$port$5(TcpClient.java:411)
        at reactor.netty.tcp.TcpClientBootstrap.configure(TcpClientBootstrap.java:39)
        at reactor.netty.tcp.TcpClientBootstrap.configure(TcpClientBootstrap.java:39)
        at reactor.netty.tcp.TcpClientBootstrap.configure(TcpClientBootstrap.java:39)
        at reactor.netty.tcp.TcpClientBootstrap.configure(TcpClientBootstrap.java:39)
        at reactor.netty.tcp.TcpClient.connect(TcpClient.java:196)
        at reactor.netty.http.client.HttpClientFinalizer.connect(HttpClientFinalizer.java:68)
        at reactor.netty.http.client.HttpClientFinalizer.responseConnection(HttpClientFinalizer.java:85)
        at com.azure.cosmos.implementation.http.ReactorNettyClient.send(ReactorNettyClient.java:123)
        at com.azure.cosmos.implementation.RxGatewayStoreModel.performRequest(RxGatewayStoreModel.java:159)
        at com.azure.cosmos.implementation.RxGatewayStoreModel.read(RxGatewayStoreModel.java:91)
        at com.azure.cosmos.implementation.RxGatewayStoreModel.invokeAsyncInternal(RxGatewayStoreModel.java:351)
        at com.azure.cosmos.implementation.RxGatewayStoreModel.lambda$invokeAsync$3(RxGatewayStoreModel.java:366)
        at com.azure.cosmos.implementation.BackoffRetryUtility.lambda$executeRetry$0(BackoffRetryUtility.java:34)
        at reactor.core.publisher.MonoDefer.subscribe(MonoDefer.java:44)
        ... 15 more
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
        at com.azure.cosmos.BridgeInternal.isEnableMultipleWriteLocations(BridgeInternal.java:163)
        at com.azure.cosmos.implementation.RxDocumentClientImpl.initializeGatewayConfigurationReader(RxDocumentClientImpl.java:264)
        at com.azure.cosmos.implementation.RxDocumentClientImpl.init(RxDocumentClientImpl.java:281)
        at com.azure.cosmos.implementation.AsyncDocumentClient$Builder.build(AsyncDocumentClient.java:203)
        at com.azure.cosmos.CosmosAsyncClient.<init>(CosmosAsyncClient.java:79)
        at com.azure.cosmos.CosmosClientBuilder.buildAsyncClient(CosmosClientBuilder.java:649)
        at com.azure.cosmos.CosmosClient.<init>(CosmosClient.java:30)
        at com.azure.cosmos.CosmosClientBuilder.buildClient(CosmosClientBuilder.java:661)
        at com.scalar.db.storage.cosmos.Cosmos.<init>(Cosmos.java:58)
```

However, I was able to insert data into the instance using the cosmosdb sdk (without scalardb) on both nodejs and java client. Below is my scalardb configuration. I even tried to run the scalardb initialization code on one of my azure vm but didn’t work as well with the same error.
Below is my scalardb configuration

```
scalar.db.contact_points=<InstanceContactPoints>
scalar.db.contact_port=<DefaultPort>
scalar.db.username=<InstanceUsername>
scalar.db.password=<InstancePassword>
scalar.db.storage=cosmos
```

I wonder if my configuration is wrong? How do I set it up? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Your code looks good.
I'm wondering whether the `scalar.db.contact_points` has the port like `...:443` in your Scalar DB configuration.
The `scalar.db.contract_port` isn't required for Cosmos DB because the contact_point has the port. You can remove the `scalar.db.contact_port` line.

Comment: I'm sorry but I have set as you said, but it still the same error. Below is my configuration.
`scalar.db.contact_points=<Domain>:<port>`
`scalar.db.contact_port=10350 // it doesn't work even if i remove it.`
`scalar.db.username=<UserName>`
`scalar.db.password=<Password>`
`scalar.db.storage=cosmos`

Comment: Thank you for the response. The `scalar.db.contract_points` is just copied from the Keys page's URI. For example, `https://my-cosmos12.documents.azure.com:443/`

Comment: I'm sorry after I set my `scalar.db.contract_points` to an URI, my transaction object is blocking forever and nothing happens, no error message or any message at all. `DistributedTransactionManager db = Guice.createInjector(new TransactionModule(cosmosDBConfig))
                .getInstance(TransactionService.class); // blocked at this line` I'm sorry am I missing something?

Comment: We have a dependency issue between Spring boot and the Azure Cosmos DB SDK. It looks like the same issue. Could you get logs of Scalar DB if you have time? Related to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64240960/scalardb-qa-application-not-properly-working-with-azure-cosmos-db